# Pole/Zero existence at infinity

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform

How can poles and zeros exist at infinity?Can anybody explain using a system function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider a general rational transfer function of order $N$, first with an equal number of zeros and poles:

$$ \begin{align}
H(z) & = A \prod_{n=1}^N \frac{z - q_n}{z - p_n} \\
& =  A \frac{\prod_{n=1}^N z - q_n}{\prod_{n=1}^N z - p_n} \\
& =  A \frac{\prod_{n=1}^N q_n - z }{\prod_{n=1}^N p_n - z} \\
& =  B \frac{\prod_{n=1}^N 1 - \frac{z}{q_n} }{\prod_{n=1}^N 1 - \frac{z}{p_n}} \\
\end{align} $$

where $ B = A \prod_{n=1}^N \frac{q_n}{p_n}$ .

now suppose that the number of zeros is actually less than the number of poles.  we *could* express the transfer function as

$$ H(z) = C \frac{\prod_{n=1}^M 1 - \frac{z}{q_n} }{\prod_{n=1}^N 1 - \frac{z} {p_n}} $$

where $M<N$. or we can express it as

$$ H(z) = B \frac{\prod_{n=1}^N 1 - \frac{z}{q_n} }{\prod_{n=1}^N 1 - \frac{z} {p_n}} $$

where $(N-M)$ zeros have values of $\infty$ which make $\frac{z}{q_n}$ disappear (for those zeros), leaving only $1$ as a factor in the transfer function.

at the moment, i am not sure what to do with the $A$, $B$, or $C$ factors which might have an $\infty$ in them.  i'll worry about that later.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you two simple examples to build up some intuition. Imagine a causal impulse response with $h[0]=0$:

$$H(z)=h[1]z^{-1}+h[2]z^{-2}+\ldots\tag{1}$$

In this case you get

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}H(z)=0$$

This is of course due to the negative powers of $z$ in (1).

Now imagine a non-causal impulse response that starts at $n=-1$, such as:

$$H(z)=h[-1]z+h[0]+h[1]z^{-1}\tag{2}$$

Now you have

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}H(z)=\infty$$

This pole is of course caused by the positive power of $z$ in (2).

Note that the transfer function of a causal impulse response can never have poles at infinity because you don't get any positive powers of $z$.

Comment: so Matt, are you saying that, for a causal discrete-time system, the number of zeros **can** exceed the number of poles?

Comment: well, it's a salient point that you **almost** made but did not.  normally, i would consider that a tad "incomplete".  it's your answer.  it speaks to an issue my answer did not (i didn't say *why* there might be fewer zeros than poles or fewer poles than zeros) but didn't quite finish the point.

Comment: BTW, if i were you and worried about misinterpretation of an answer, i would worry a lot more about the other two questions.  despite the case you make, you would almost certainly get the exam question wrong if it were *"true or false, $y[n] = p \cdot y[n-1] + x[n]$ is an LTI system."*  you would protest to the professor, but you would still get that question wrong because, at least in the EE discipline, it would not be interpreted as you do.